# ReferenceError: Holder is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm loading all node-module using

require('./node_modules/holderjs/holder.js');

in lib.js which is getting loaded in Index.html
I can see other node-modules, getting loaded from same lib.js file (loaded as same as holder.js) but see following error msg when function referencing this js are called.

> ReferenceError: Holder is not defined
>       at Object.link (http://localhost:9000/app/assets/js/app.js:1:35913)
>       at http://localhost:9000/app/assets/js/lib.js:1:1068592

these files app.js (application code file) and lib.js (all 3rd party module library files) are created by concatenating all application and node-module files respectively.

Following is Webpack config used for it :

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'lib',
        filename: 'lib.js',
        minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: { warnings: false },
        comments: false,
        mangle: false,
        minimize: false
    })
]
```